# For iOS NSUrlRequest, the parameter timeoutInterval: seems doesn't work for post request type

Tags: timeout, nsurlrequest

For iOS NSUrlRequest, the parameter timeoutInterval: seems doesn't work for post request type, I set timeout value as 20.0f, but error response doesn't come back when server hangup during my experiment, however it works well for GET request type.

Apple doesn't tell this secret during its API description. How about using NSTimer or any other solution to achieve it?  Anyone who knows please share and thanks in advance.

```
[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: cachePolicy: timeoutInterval:];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a timer to control timeout issue is workable.

Comment: For NSUrlRequest, its timeout value only works for GET request, but not POST.